# Convert methods from Java-actionscript to ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, types

I'm tring to convert the following 3 methods from java-actionscript to Objective C.
Part of my confusion I think is not knowing what Number types, primitives I should be using. ie in actionscript you have only Number, int, and uint. These are the 3 functions I am trying to convert

```
 public function normalize(value:Number, minimum:Number, maximum:Number):Number
    {
        return (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
    }

    public function interpolate(normValue:Number, minimum:Number, maximum:Number):Number
    {
        return minimum + (maximum - minimum) * normValue;
    }

    public function map(value:Number, min1:Number, max1:Number, min2:Number, max2:Number):Number
    {
        return interpolate( normalize(value, min1, max1), min2, max2);
    }
```

This is what I have so far

```
-(float) normalize:(float*)value 
 withMinimumValue:(float*)minimum 
 withMaximumValue:(float*)maximum
 {
 return (value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum);
 }

-(float) interpolate:(float*)normValue
  withMinimumValue:(float*)minimum 
  withMaximumValue:(float*)maximum
 {
return minimum + (maximum - minimum) * normValue;
 }

-(float) map:(float*)value 
 withMinimumValue1:(float*)min1 
 withMaximumValue1:(float*)max1 
 withMinimumValue2:(float*)min2 
 withMaximumValue2:(float*)max2
 {
return interpolate( normalize(value, min1, max1), min2, max2);
 }
```

Comment: Oh, and (float*) is nonsense in the above-- you'd just use (float) as your argument types... not a `pointer to a float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're looking for a primitive type (not an object) that can handle non-integer values, `float` is probably fine (or CGFloat, as suggested by Chris)
- unless your functions need to modify their arguments, you want the arguments to be just `float` not `float *`.
- you are mixing up Objective-C message passing and plain C function invocation syntax: your example declares them as instance methods, but you're calling them like a function (won't work).

To match your declarations, the invocation would look something like:

```
return [self interpolate:
           [self normalize:value withMinimumValue:min1 withMaximumValue:max1]
           withMinimumValue:min2
           withMaximumValue:max2];
```

- Because your `interpolate`, `normalize`, and `map` methods do not rely on any variables from the current object instance, they might be better off as objective-C class methods (or even as plain C functions).

Answer (score 1):

Given that none of your methods require any other state to work, all are basic math kinda stuff, and all are pretty straightforward, I would skip Objective-C entirely and just go with straight C.  Something like:

```
static inline float normalize(float val, float min, float max) {
    return (val - min) / (max - min);
}
```

Stick that in a header file somewhere in your project and be done with it.  Do the same for `interpolate` and `map`.

Note: as others have mentioned, you might want to change the type to CGFloat, if needed.

Comment: I think using CGFloat is dependent on what these numbers are for.  If they are coordinates or colour values, then fine - CGFloat.  If they represent some data that is part of the model, it would be better to use float or double depending on the required precision.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apple's frameworks, these are the conversions you'll probably want to use:

- `Number` =~ `CGFloat`
- `int` =~ `NSInteger`
- `uint` =~ `NSUInteger`

Comment: Is CGFloat used in Cocoa these days? I though that was mainly an iPhonism. Could be a brain fart, though.

Comment: CGFloat has been in OS X since 10.5